# OnLogin evnet not firing on agsXMPP

Tags: c#, openfire, agsxmpp

I have an issue with agsXMPP onLogin event.
when I was working on local machine everything worked just fine and when I established a connection with a server it seems that the onLogin() event is not fired up, although the connection state after I open() the connection is "Connected"
this is how I establish the connection :

```
        Jid jid = new Jid(username, GlobalVar.server, "IM");

        _connection.Server = GlobalVar.server;
        _connection.Username = jid.User;
        _connection.Password = psw;
        _connection.Resource = jid.Resource;
        _connection.Priority = 1;
        _connection.Port = port;
        _connection.UseSSL = useSLL;
        _connection.AutoResolveConnectServer = true;
        _connection.UseCompression = false;
        _connection.EnableCapabilities = true;
        _connection.Open();

        SetDiscoInfo();
        this.dadForm.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

        MessageBox.Show(_connection.XmppConnectionState.ToString());
```

I tested the Openfire server with Spark IM, it seems that it works just fine so the problem is only in the configuration of my app 
any ideas on how to solve this problem please

Answer (score 1):

When you try to connect to an external server make sure that the property **Server** point on the server name and the **ConnectServer** on the IP address like this :

```
        _connection.ConnectServer = "server IP adress";
        _connection.Server = "server name";
```